# Transfer file between puppet-managed servers

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

We have a server (managed by puppet) that generates a file once per day.  Is there an approach I could use to make puppet do the following:

- Recognize that the file is there on server A
- Upload it to the puppet master
- Ensure its existence on puppet-managed server B
- Reload a service on server B

It's really the recognizing and uploading that I'm not clear on. I think I understand how to ensure the existence on server B and reload the service.

Any patterns or documentation would be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: does it need to be on the master?

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a look into [exported resources](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/exported_resources.html).

You could define an additional resource using a custom fact as source for the file contents:

```
node servera {
    @@file { "/generated/file"
        ensure => present,
        content => $::myspecialfilecontent
        tag => myspecialfile,
    }
}
```

and realise the resource on serverb:

```
node serverb {
    File <<| tag == 'myspecialfile' |>> {
        notify => Service["your_service"],
    } 
}
```

the custom puppet fact could look like follows (put it in a modules/.../lib/facter/myspecialfilecontent.rb file and enable pluginsync):

```
filename = '/generated/file'
Facter.add(:myspecialfilecontent) do
    setcode do
        if File.file?(filename)
            File.read(filename)
        end
    end
end
```

you need `storeconfigs = true` (puppetdb) for that though.

This is not a very clean solution but it could work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have a common class or node (like the default) that applies to all the nodes managed by puppet.

Here you create the policy to manage the file created daily, but only a virtual resource.

```
node default {
  $fsufix = strftime("%y_%m_%d")
  @file { "everyday_file" :
    path => "/scratch/usern/file_${fsufix}",
    ensure => present,
  }
}
```

Then for the serverA, you just need to check whether that file is present by realizing the virtual resource we just created earlier :

```
node 'serverA' inherits default {
  realize(File["everyday_file"])
}
```

After this you want serverB to do the same as serverA plus refresh a service if the file is created or modified :

```
node 'serverB' inherits default {
  realize(File["everyday_file"])
  service { "mysqld" :
    ensure => running,
    hasrestart => true,
    subscribe => File ["everyday_file"],
  }
}
```

Comment: are you sure this will catch the content of the file? IMHO when you specify a file without source/content puppet just ensures the file is there but does not care about its content...

Comment: question of OP has nothing about the content of the file. In any case,  since this file is being produced everyday, I believe the content might be different and may need some kind of template, but that's another question...

Comment: as far as I understood it the file itself is generated by an application and not from within puppet... But of course I could be wrong...